# Google map in UICollectionView loading and scrolling issue

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, background, uicollectionview

I have implemented an UICollectionView with horizontal free (not pagination) scrolling. And every UICollectionViewCell is loading real google map (Image attached). Currently, it flickers on scrolling, I need smooth scrolling and smooth loading of map.

What I tried,

1. I tried to load google map in background and then update the cell in main UI thread but it crashes.

Logs says: (sharedResourceCache_ != nil) was false: Shared resource cache not populated.

Here is the code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {           
        var getMap = self.getMapViewForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             cell.contentView.addSubview(getMap)
        }
    }

func getMapViewForCell(cell: CardCollectionViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIView {

    let randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, maxRange: (latArray.count-1))

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(getLatitude(randomIndex), longitude:getLongitude(randomIndex), zoom:16)
    var mapFrame = cell.mapView.frame
    mapFrame.size.height -= cell.name.frame.size.height
    mapFrame.origin.y = cell.name.frame.origin.y + cell.name.frame.size.height

    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(mapFrame, camera:camera)
    mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = camera.target
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "homeicon.png")
    marker.map = mapView       
    mapView.tag = 99

    return mapView
}
```

If I can load google map in background then it can solve many issues, I think.
Thanks in advance for any advice?

[image: Google map loading on UICollectionViewCell, horizontal scrolling]

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?